# Get absolute bounding box of Chunk in iText 2.1.7?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

In this example:

```
Document document=new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("hello.pdf"));
document.open();  
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(new Chunk("Hello ");
paragraph.add(new Chunk("world");
paragraph.add(new Chunk(" in");
paragraph.add(new Chunk(" iText 2.7.1");
document.add(paragraph);
document.close();
```

How can I get the absolute position, width, and height on page of the second chunk "world" ? In other words, the bounding box in user space.

Comment: There's [never](http://itextpdf.com/history/) been a 2.7.1 version of iText. Do you mean 2.1.7?

Comment: Now corrected in the text to 2.1.7. Thanks Alexis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic tag facility provided on Chunks.

```
    public class PEvents extends PdfPageEventHelper {
      @Override
      public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter w, Document doc, Rectangle r, String tag) {
         if (tag.equals("mytag")) {             
           //here r is the rectangle of "world" chunk
         }
      }
    }
    writer.setPageEvent(new PEvents());
    Chunk world = new Chunk("world");
    world.setGenericTag("mytag");
    paragraph.add(world);
    . . .
```